has anything gone wrong with mpchess
I have used the mpchess package to put chess diagrams in multiple documents and everything was fine.
Suddenly after some update all the files that contains mpchess were not compiling until you remove the mpchess code!
I tried to put again a diagram in a document and succeeded but the diagram will not align correctly with text!
here is an example
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,arabic, provide=*, bidi=basic, layout=counters.tabular]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{amiri}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{mpgraphics}
%\usepackage{uni-titlepage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fontscale}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{latexcolors}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\setlength\columnsep{12pt}
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic}
\newcommand{\en}{\foreignlanguage{english}}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\everymplib{input mpchess;}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{skak}
%\usepackage{chessboard}
%\usepackage{texmate}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\chessfont}{mpchess font}
\newcommand\bP{{\chessfont \char"265F}} % black Pawn
\newcommand\bN{{\chessfont \char"265E}} % black Knight
\newcommand\bB{{\chessfont \char"265D}} % black Bishop
\newcommand\bR{{\chessfont \char"265C}} % black Rook
\newcommand\bQ{{\chessfont \char"265B}} % black Queen
\newcommand\bK{{\chessfont \char"265A}} % black King
\newcommand\wP{{\chessfont \char"2659}} % white Pawn
\newcommand\wN{{\chessfont \char"2658}} % white Knight
\newcommand\wB{{\chessfont \char"2657}} % white Bishop
\newcommand\wR{{\chessfont \char"2656}} % white Rook
\newcommand\wQ{{\chessfont \char"2655}} % white Queen
\newcommand\wK{{\chessfont \char"2654}} % white King
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
هذا النص هو مثال لنص يمكن أن يستبدل في نفس المساحة، لقد تم توليد هذا النص من مولد النص العربى، حيث يمكنك أن تولد مثل هذا النص أو العديد من النصوص الأخرى إضافة إلى زيادة عدد الحروف التى يولدها التطبيق.
إذا كنت تحتاج إلى عدد أكبر من الفقرات يتيح لك مولد النص العربى زيادة عدد الفقرات كما تريد، النص لن يبدو مقسما ولا يحوي أخطاء لغوية، مولد النص العربى مفيد لمصممي المواقع على وجه الخصوص، حيث يحتاج العميل فى كثير من الأحيان أن يطلع على صورة حقيقية لتصميم الموقع.
ومن هنا وجب على المصمم أن يضع نصوصا مؤقتة على التصميم ليظهر للعميل الشكل كاملاً،دور مولد النص العربى أن يوفر على المصمم عناء البحث عن نص بديل لا علاقة له بالموضوع الذى يتحدث عنه التصميم فيظهر بشكل لا يليق.
هذا النص يمكن أن يتم تركيبه على أي تصميم دون مشكلة فلن يبدو وكأنه نص منسوخ، غير منظم، غير منسق، أو حتى غير مفهوم. لأنه مازال نصاً بديلاً ومؤقتاً.

هذا النص هو مثال لنص يمكن أن يستبدل في نفس المساحة، لقد تم توليد هذا النص من مولد النص العربى، حيث يمكنك أن تولد مثل هذا النص أو العديد من النصوص الأخرى إضافة إلى زيادة عدد الحروف التى يولدها التطبيق.
إذا كنت تحتاج إلى عدد أكبر من الفقرات يتيح لك مولد النص العربى زيادة عدد الفقرات كما تريد، النص لن يبدو مقسما ولا يحوي أخطاء لغوية، مولد النص العربى مفيد لمصممي المواقع على وجه الخصوص، حيث يحتاج العميل فى كثير من الأحيان أن يطلع على صورة حقيقية لتصميم الموقع.
ومن هنا وجب على المصمم أن يضع نصوصا مؤقتة على التصميم ليظهر للعميل الشكل كاملاً،دور مولد النص العربى أن يوفر على المصمم عناء البحث عن نص بديل لا علاقة له بالموضوع الذى يتحدث عنه التصميم فيظهر بشكل لا يليق.
هذا النص يمكن أن يتم تركيبه على أي تصميم دون مشكلة فلن يبدو وكأنه نص منسوخ، غير منظم، غير منسق، أو حتى غير مفهوم. لأنه مازال نصاً بديلاً ومؤقتاً.
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(0);
set_color_theme("Classical");
set_coordinates_position("outside");
init_backboard;
draw backboard;
init_chessboard;
draw chessboard;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}


Can the issue be reproduced with a font from TeX Live? Most of us won't be able to compile this.

the font now is amiri which I belive is more popular in tex.

Nothing changed, you only forgot to switch locally to english, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683014/2388

yes,
and it is my question too.
